# wipe disk with dd

Tags: shell, dd

I know we can wipe a hard disk using random data or zeros, but is it possible to wipe using a fixed string ?

e.g. is this correct?

```
dd if="string" of=/my/harddisk ...
```

Also, does the options below say to copy only the 400th sector?

```
bs=512 count=1 skip=399
```

Comment: @SiegeX: Greg's right. You can attack this with `/bin/sh` or whatever, but it is a hard problem (because of the interactions of multiple levels of hardware and software caching between `dd` and the disk) and one that has already been solved by experts.

Answer (score 4):

```
dd if=<(yes "string") of=/my/harddisk
```

> Also, does the options below say to copy only the 400th sector?

No, it says to skip over 399 **BLOCKS** and write 512 bytes worth of data from that point.

Comment: hi,  so how do I get only the 400th sector? I though 512 bytes is 1 sector and I have count=1 ? thanks

Comment: Nice use of 'yes'

Comment: @user bytes/sector is not a constant. On Linux you can get this information via `fdisk -b`, it *may* be 512 but it doesn't *have* to be.

Comment: @Siegex, thanks. Assuming its 512bytes/sector which is already specified using bs=512, how should i get only the 400th sector? I thought by skipping 399 blocks, and setting count=1, I should get the 400th sector. thanks

Comment: @user You would set `bs` equal to the sector size. If your sector size is 512 bytes, then blocks and sectors would be identical with `bs=512`.  See [THIS LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector) for a bit more detail, especially the **History** section

Comment: @Siegex, so bs=512 count=1 skip=399 is correct for getting 400th sector? right? if not, what should it be?

Comment: @user: yes, that is my conclusion for a sector size of 512b